# Lagrange/Rolle question

Tags: calculus

Prove that:

- for every $x>0:\arctan x+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$
- for $-1\leq x\leq1: \arcsin x+\arccos x=\pi/2$

This are some question I got on my Lagrange worksheet. Can someone help me with a solution with Lagrange/Rolle sentences?

Comment: Show that the derivative vanishes. The mean value theorem (a consequence of Rolle) implies that the function is constant. To determine that constant use $x=1$ or the limit $x\to \infty$.

Comment: The functions are constant sret at their initial or final values of function and so all intermediate differential  incremented values are also same. Draw a right triangle with acute angles $x, y= \pi/2-x$ for the exact verification.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function
$$ f(x) = \arctan(x) + \arctan(1/x). $$
Its derivative is
$$ f'(x)= \frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{1}{1+1/x^2} \frac{-1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}=0. $$
Therefore the function is constant over $(0,\infty)$. Then $f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: it's constant because it's derivative is 0.

Comment: What are you talking about? The function is differentiable, so continuity it's automatic.

Comment: ok ok no problem :)

Comment: :) ............